# How can i filter specific font faces with HTMLPurifier?

Tags: php, html, fonts, wysiwyg, htmlpurifier

-

in my current project, I have got a HTML-WYSIWYG Editor. Users can use different Webfonts to design their texts.

The Editor I am using is [NiceEdit](http://nicedit.com/). It generates code like this:

```
        <font face="comic sans ms">Comic Sans</font><br>
        <font face="georgia">Georgia</font><br>
        <font face="helvetica">Helvetica</font><br>
```

I want to filter the fonts and only want to allow specific fonts viaHTMLPurifier.

so my Idea was to customize the config like this:

```
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); //TODO: remove this later!
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(
$def->addAttribute('font', 'face', 'Text#impact, georgia');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

---

So in this case I only want to allow the fonts "*impact*" and "*georgia*".

But it doesn't work this way, all fonts still go through and are displayed.

Would be great, if someone could help me out here!

Thank you!
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override the logic for filtering font-family and font. I think this will be tricky to do correctly externally, so you might just edit `AttrDef/CSS/FontFamily.php` manually to apply your restrictions.

Comment: Hey thanks for your Tip, but I don't really get the whole logic behind that specific file to code that kind off extension by myself, I guess :/

Comment: You don't really have to understand the entire logic of the file. All you need to know is that the first argument of the function is the font name in question, so just check if it's equal to your allowed ones and return an appropriate value (the string if it's good, false if it should be removed).

Comment: Hi Edward, thank you very much for your tip! I tried to implement that little "hack" but i didn't get the results I wanted.
I solved this by filtering not allowed fonts by writing an extra function which takes care of this now.